# Frequency modulation: which algorithm for discrete signals (Java, Swift, etc.)

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-modulation, java

I'm writing an audio app in Swift - and one task consists in frequency modulation of a given signal (microphone input or sound file) - thus I'm iterating through all frames of a buffer like

```
let leftSourceData = readBuffer.floatChannelData?[0]
let rightSourceData = readBuffer.floatChannelData?[1]

let leftTargetData = renderBuffer.floatChannelData?[0]
let rightTargetData = renderBuffer.floatChannelData?[1]

for i in 0..<Int(readBuffer.frameLength) {

   // TODO: perform frequency modulation on source data, writing the results to target data
   leftTargetData[i] = ???
   rightTargetData[i] = ???
                   
}
```

The equation for Frequency Modulation is clear - you'll find in the Internet s.th. like that:

```
 f(t) = A sin(2*pi*fc*t + I * sin(2*pi*fm*t))
 with fc = carrier frequency, fm = modulation frequency
 and I = modulation index.
```

The above-mentioned equation only covers a sinusoidal input signal - anyhow, I want to modulate an arbitrary signal - thus s.th. different than a pure sine wave.

For amplitude modulation, I've used the following algorithm (within the loop) which works well for Swift and iOS:

```
let val: Double = sin(Double(2 * modulationFrequency) * Double(index) * Double.pi / Double(renderBuffer.format.sampleRate))
leftTargetData?[i] = Float(val) * (leftSourceData?[i] ?? 0)
rightTargetData?[i] = Float(val) * (rightSourceData?[i] ?? 0)
```

How can I do the same for FM?

Comment: What's your specific application? Are you looking at audio effects like Chorus, Flanger, Phase ?

Comment: I want to produce a Silent Subliminal - thus shifting a human voice to a higher frequency so that it can't be heard by humans

Comment: If you just to shift the whole audible spectrum you can just multiply with a cosine of something like 25 kHz or so. That will require your sample rate to be high enough, so some upsampling would likely be needed.

Comment: thank you Hilmar - what you're talking about is amplitude modulation - the same I've described in my code above. But what I need now is frequency modulation ... it's for experimental reasons, just to figure out if AM or FM is more efficient for my purposes.

Comment: Nope, it's not the same. Amplitude modulation is $y(t) = (1 + m\cdot cos(\omega_At))\cdot x(t)$. Carrier modulation is $y(t) = cos(\omega_Ft)\cdot)x(t)$. Note that typically $\omega_A$ is significantly smaller than your signal frequencies and small and $\omega_F$ needs to be bigger.